# Possible to use routes.rb for a rewrite rule?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get rails+jammit+Cloudfront working. The last thing I need to figure out is how to cache bust. I'm using heroku. Below is the step for apache. Is it possible to do the same thing in the Rails route.rb file?

```
# Cache-busting rule for CloudFront.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/r-.+/(images|javascripts|stylesheets|system|assets)/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [L]
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: +1 I need to integrate CSS/JS from disparate sources, and they all refer to images in different folders, like /image, /images and even /img.  As a quick fix I need to be able to say in routes.rb:  match "/img/*" => "/assets/*".

Comment: So are you looking to bend mod_rewrite into a variant of find, so on receipt of a request for   /img/abc.png  that dosen't exist in the filesystem, it goes looking to see if there's a: /image/abc.png  OR /images/abv.png  OR  /wibble/abc.png ? If this is the case then it's possible, either as an inefficient set of rules in a .htaccess file or via a slightly more efficient RewriteMap in your httpd.conf.